# Cloudinary Upload

Tags: typescript, database, prisma, cloudinary

I am trying to use cloudinary to upload picture on my prisma studio for the restaurant project i am currently building.

I am receiving this error when i console of google chrome as it is not uploading to my prisma studio.

Access to fetch at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/lamadev/image' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
const AddPage = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<Inputs>({
    title: "",
    desc: "",
    price: 0,
    catSlug: "",
  });

  const [option, setOption] = useState<Option>({
    title: "",
    additionalPrice: 0,
  });

  const [options, setOptions] = useState<Option[]>([]);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File>();

  const router = useRouter();

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (status === "unauthenticated" || !session?.user.isAdmin) {
    router.push("/");
  }

  const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    setInputs((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    });
  };
  const changeOption = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setOption((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    });
  };

  const handleChangeImg = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const item = (target.files as FileList)[0];
    setFile(item);
  };

  const upload = async () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file!);
    data.append("upload_preset", "restaurant");

    const res = await fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/lamadev/image", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      body: data,
    });

    const resData = await res.json();
    return resData.url;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const url = await upload();
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          img: url,
          ...inputs,
          options,
        }),
      });

      const data = await res.json();

      router.push(`/product/${data.id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };`
``
```

Comment: have a look at https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010811739-Access-Control-Allow-Origin and let us know if it helps